# How to calculate costing of invoking lambda triggers with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I was looking around AWS Cognito pricing model and was unable to find any document regarding quota for invoking Cognito Lambda triggers. There is quota for Lambda functions(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) but nothing about Lambda triggers with Cognito. Can  anyone help with the relevant document/information for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pay for the triggers. Just for the lambda functions that were triggered.

Comment: So let's say that we have created 2 lambda functions and have uploaded them as post authentication lambda triggers and we have about 20,000 users signing in as concurrent requests per second then how would we be able to calculate the costing, would it be based on 20,000 requests(triggering the lambda function 20000 times) or would it be for 2 lambda functions? and would you be able to share any supporting doc over the same.

Comment: Lambda cost mostly depends on how much memory you allocated and how long it runs. Invocation itself is cheap, so with numbers you provided estimation is not possible. 

Take a look at AWS calculator, it's very clear https://calculator.aws/